# jQuery mobile listview refresh doesn't apply top/bottom corner classes

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile with [jQuery Mobile Router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router), to dynamically change content of listviews.

In the change handler I'm dynamically adding content to an inset listview, then calling `listview('refresh')` to re-apply all the styling to the new elements. It mostly works, however whilst it applies the `ui-corner-all` to the UL the `ui-corner-top` and `ui-corner-bottom` classes are not applied to the correct LIs so they don't get rounded corners applied.

[image: Listview without rounded corners]

I have prepared a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/robaldred/j5q75/) that demonstrates the issue.
The first page is static, the second page is generated in the rounter handler which is trigger by the jqm `beforepageshow` event

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just needed to force the refresh:

- http://jsfiddle.net/j5q75/4/

JS

```
listview.listview('refresh',true);
```

Comment: So I have to pass true to make it actually refresh, wtf :/ Thanks though